# Why don't I get a java preferences icon when I install Oracle Java 7u9 on my Mac

Tags: macos, setup, java

I have tried repeatedly to install the Oracle java runtime (Java 7 update 9) on my mac, but it doesn't work. I should just be able to [download it from oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp), mount the disk image, and click to install. Where is the preference pane icon that it promises will show up in the "Other" section of my preferences, and why does `java -version` keep telling me it is the old version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because this took me hours to figure out, and I can't find the information anywhere else. In short, it does work, but not correctly.

The first problem, no preference pane, is because Oracle is not testing on a CASE-SENSITIVE mac system. The preference pane `/Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane` is a link to the actual preference pane, supposedly `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy/JavaControlPanel.prefpane` (note the lower case `.prefpane`). If you go look, the name is really `JavaControlPanel.prefPane`. This was a capital Pane to figure out :) Just change the link:

```
sudo ln -sf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy/JavaControlPanel.prefPane /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
```

The second problem appears to be more my fault. Installing the java 7 SE jdk and not just the runtime fixed this.

PS: I'm still amazed that Apple would just delete programs from your computer with a minor upgrade. Much of the information on managing Java on your mac is now outdated (with the loss of the java preference app from the `/Applications/Utilities` folder).

Comment: Followed the step, still I don't see it in /Applications/Utilities